# matlab generate c code with get column values error

Tags: matlab, codegen

i have meet a problem when using coder to generate C coder.
matlab function contains a sentences like

```matlab
function [ B ] = fn1( A )
    a = A(:,2);
    B = a+1;
end
```

A is input parameter, 4x2 matrix.

i got c code:

```c
void fn1(const float A[8], float B[4])
{
  int i0;
  for (i0 = 0; i0 < 4; i0++) {
    B[i0] = A[4 + i0] + 1.0F;
  }
}
```

B is not then 2nd column of A.

in matab "define input types", i changed row/column ,it still not working.

i'm using matlab 2016b. is there additional setting or advice to solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me. If A is a 4x2 matrix, then the 2nd column elements are linear indexed 4,5,6,7 in a 0-based indexing scheme as in C, and you add 1 to each element to produce B.  That is what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

KEYWORD: array layout.
matlab array is column layout while C array is row layout. this mismatch causes the problem. matlab introduces 'array layout' option in R2019 or ealier, but it's not available in R2016.